# Get a TK() object from another method

Tags: python, object, tkinter

#### Goal

I want to create a popup window with buttons that closes when the mouse leaves the window. (It is a submenu of a program).

To do that I have a function that is called if the popup window should be opened. It contains following code:

```
master = Tk()
fpy.ui.menu.submenu(master=master,[...more parameters...])
mainloop()
```

and a method (fpy.ui.menu.submenu(...)) to create everything else.
This function should stay as clean as possible. It's part of an API I'm building for my future projects.

```
def submenu(master,[...more parameters...]):
    master.overrideredirect(True)
    a_frame = Frame(master, bg="grey")
    #[codeblock to generate buttons]
    a_frame.bind("<Leave>", destroy)
    a_frame.pack()
```

```
a_frame.bind("<Leave>", destroy)
```

calls the function 'function' when the mouse leaves the frame. And now my problem starts. the 'destroy' function should destroy my root (in this case called master).

#### Problem:

```
def destroy():
    #how can I get the master-object?
    master.destroy()
```

This will cause an error! How can I reach the Object I want to destroy from this method?

#### Info:

- the function 'destroy' gets started
- I didn't manage to transmitt the master object as parameter
- please ignore the dots at the beginning of a line. the Stack Exchange editor doesn't accept indented code.

Comment: If you aren't passing `master` in as a parameter then it will need to be defined as `self.master = master` at the top of whatever Class you are working from.  Then call `self.master.destroy()`

Comment: What do you mean "The Stack Exchange editor doesn't accept indented code"? Indented code works just fine.  I've removed the dots, since the code is illegal syntax otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1: Pass it as an argument

You could pass it to your `destroy()` function using a `lambda` statement:

```
a_frame.bind("<Leave>", lambda: destroy(master))
```

Then modify the signature of your destroy function:

```
def destroy(master):
    master.destroy()
```

### Option 2: Invoke the destroy method on master directly

Same `lambda` statement as before, except now we just call the method directly rather than handling it in another function.

```
a_frame.bind("<Leave>", lambda: master.destroy())
```

Of course, this isn't an option if you want to do other stuff in your `destroy()` function.

Comment: Ok, your proposed code works with a slight modification: `a_frame.bind("<Leave>", lambda x: master.destroy())`. I don't know why I need the x in there, but now it works.